# Regular expression for finding tag numbers in a list of cats

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to match the tag numbers in a list of cats:

```
Abyssinian 987
Burmese a1a
Dragon Li 2B
987 Cat
cat 987 Toyger
cat A1A Siamese
1
```

The tag numbers for the list of cats would be:

```
987
a1a
2B
987
987
A1A
1
```

I've tried using the regular expression:

```
\b[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b
```

The problem is that it will match "cat" and "Li" (in Dragon Li). It should only match the tag number.

The requirements for a tag number are:

- 1-3 characters, it must contain at least one integer (0-9)
- It can appear at any place in the string

As a side note, I am using Postgres regular expressions, which I think use POSIX regular expressions. (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: What do you mean by `trying to match the tag` *exactly*? Depending on the use case, a dramatically faster solution might be possible without regular expressions. And is there always exactly one tag in the string that fits the description?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter my goal is to extract the substring from the text, in this case, get only the tag information. I was using the string function regexp_matches to do this, but if you could provide a better way of doing this, that would be great.

Comment: Matching two tables by way of an regular expression could get *very* expensive. Simple extraction is not that sensitive to performance implications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT substring(cat FROM '\m(?=\w{0,2}\d)\w{1,3}\M') AS tag
FROM   cat;
```

`\m` and `\M` .. [beginning and end of a word.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)
`(?=\w{0,2}\d)`.. [positive lookahead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE)
`\w{1,3}`  .. [1-3 word characters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE)

Assuming there is a single match in every string, [`substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) (without the "global" switch `'g'`) is better for the job than `regexp_matches()`, which would return an *array* (even for a single match).
`substring()` is also a bit faster.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e548c/2)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(?=\w*?\d)\w{1,3}\b
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gN3gF2)

**Test:** Using `grep -P`:

```
grep -oP '\b(?=\w*?\d)\w{1,3}\b' file
987
a1a
2B
987
987
A1A
1
```

Comment: abc-Burmese-a1a matches abc

Comment: Actually I provided regex101 link with detailed explanation of this regex but I could have posted the screenshot here also.

Comment: @anubhava: I have seen the explanation at the link, that's why I removed my comment right after I posted it. It's a very nice regular expression (+1). The problem is, it does not work in Postgres. Posting another answer.